# Why the file upload is not functioning in following form?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, input

I'm using smarty and PHP for my website. Following is my form code from smarty template.

```
<form id="manage_reply_enquiry" name="manage_reply_enquiry" method="post" action="{$control_url}modules/enquiries/reply_to_enquiry.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>{'To Name'|signal_on_error:$error_msg:'contact_name'} :</label>
            <div class="form-element">
              <input type="text" name="contact_full_name" id="contact_full_name" value="{$data.contact_full_name|capitalize}" class="">
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>{'To Email'|signal_on_error:$error_msg:'email'} :</label>
            <div class="form-element">
              <input type="text" name="contact_email_id" id="contact_email_id" value="{$data.contact_email_id}" class="">
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>{'Reply'|signal_on_error:$error_msg:'reply'} :</label>
            <div class="form-element">
              <textarea name="reply" id="reply" cols="60" rows="12">{$data.reply}</textarea>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>{'Upload File'|signal_on_error:$error_msg:'reply_file_name'} :</label>
            <div class="form-element">
              <p class=""><input type="file" id="reply_file_name" name="reply_file_name" /></p>
              <div class="input-info"> <span class="required">Note* (Image size should be less then 1 mb and alowed format types are CSV, XLS)</span></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <input type="hidden" name="contact_id" value="{$data.contact_id}" />
          <input type="hidden" name="from_date" value="{$from_date}" />
          <input type="hidden" name="to_date" value="{$to_date}" />
          <input type="hidden" name="op" value="{$op}" />
          <li>
            <label></label>
            <div class="form-element">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="c-btn" value="Send">
              <input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" class="c-btn" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='{$control_url}modules/enquiries/view_contact_us.php?page={$page}&from_date={$from_date}&to_date={$to_date}'">
            </div>
          </li>                
        </ul>
      </form>
```

If I print the Posted data in the **reply_to_enquiry.php** file, I'm getting following data:

```
Array
(
    [contact_full_name] => ABCD
    [contact_email_id] => abcd@gmail.com
    [reply] => How are you now?
    [contact_id] => 59
    [from_date] => 10/09/2000
    [to_date] => 10/09/2013
    [op] => view
    [submit] => Send
)
```

Can you tell me why I'm not able to get the value from file control named **reply_file_name** from the form? I couldn't get why this is happening. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may take a look in `$_FILES`

Answer (score 0):

When you do an upload in PHP, the informations relative to the uploaded file are in the `$_FILES` variable.

Here a minimal upload script. (don't use it in production environment)

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_FILES['reply_file_name'])){
    $target = "some/path/".basename($_FILES['reply_file_name']['name']) ;
    print_r($_FILES);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['reply_file_name']['tmp_name'],$target)) echo "OK!";//$chmod o+rw some/path

    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Note: this doesn't check for errors and is pretty insecure, although it illustrates the point

Comment: @DamienPirsy sure that's just an excerpt to help him to find his own script ;)